# How do I get my S2 to communicate with the bluetooth keyboard again

Tags: samsung, external-keyboard

I purchased the Samsung keyboard case when I bought my 9.7 inch S2 at Best Buy. After a short while, the bluetooth connection was lost and I was unable to get it back, so back to the store. They could not get it to work either, and replaced the keyboard with a new one, which paired up and worked fine for awhile... then after a few days, it stopped working. Both devices are fully charged. I have tried rebooting several times. The keyboard shows up on the bluetooth screen, but when I select it, it briefly pops up a message saying something like "unable to communicate with S2 keyboard". I plan to take the tablet to Thailand in a couple of months and would like the keyboard to function as more than just extra weight. Maybe I got two lemons, but I don't have much faith in just trading it in again for another keyboard... and other than this issue, I love the tablet. I am a touch typer, so using the onscreen keyboard is a big leap backward.

Comment: did you ever get a solution to this? This same thing has happened to me and im stuck on vacation in Japan with no keyboard now. Any advice would help!

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the keyboard and go into blue tooth settings.  Hold down on the selected device and it will pair.  Mine prompted me to enter a code on the keyboard then it was paired! It just came to me all of the sudden after searching for answers so i figured I'd post what worked.

Answer (score 0):

switch the keyboard off. on the top right center you will see a key that has the blue Bluetooth logo on it. hold that key down and switch on the keyboard. keep holding until the light turns blue, yellow, red. now you can pair the bluetooth keyboard to the tablet

Answer (score 0):

keyboard was paired but wouldnt connect. tried in a different rooom from where my wifi router was andd it connected right away